# How to load javascript including jquery commands from database

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, dynamic

I am building a cms in C# (.NET) and all content is stored in the database. This includes on-page css and on-page js code. The issue I have is that the handler that loads the js script is processed before the page template so if the js includes any jquery object commands, they throw an error because jquery itself has not been loaded and initialized yet.

For example, my template has a line on the master page near the top like...

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

as you might expect. Then, further down I load page-specific js code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Handlers/ServeJsByID.ashx?pgsid=<%=pgsID %>&jsid=<%=jsID %>"></script>
```

where pgsID is the id of the current page and jsID is the id of the javascript record I want to load.

I assume this has something to do with the lifecycle of the .NET page but I have no idea how to force the js load through the handler to occur AFTER the page has already loaded and processed the jquery.js file.

I tried using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript in the code behind but still get 'Object Expected" errors.

How can I load javascript in code behind and have it processed AFTER the jquery file is loaded?

Comment: I think this may be a c#/.net problem as opposed to jQuery. You really need to load the jQuery file first if you want to have any jQuery commands execute - that's just how it is.

Comment: I understand that Matt. My issue is that it is a CMS with hundreds of websites. I don't want hundreds of js files. I need each client to be able to customize their menus, etc, and have the js code stored in the database.

Comment: Ok. I'm just saying, it's not a jQuery issue. By the way, I didn't downvote you I just retagged your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this:

```
$.getScript("http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/color/jquery.color.js", function() {
   $("#go").click(function(){
     $(".block").animate( { backgroundColor: "pink" }, 1000)
      .delay(500)
      .animate( { backgroundColor: "blue" }, 1000);
   });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: This works! Thanks! I can hard-code each page to load that page's on-page javascript database entry by id